# Trying to install mtrack, but get unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, xorg, dependencies

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.4 on my Macbook Air (late 2015). I want to fix the horrendous touchpad configuration that comes by default. So I searched and found that `mtrack` does that. So I tried to install `mtrack` with `sudo apt-get install -f xserver-xorg-input-mtrack`. But then I get an error

`xserver-xorg-input-mtrack : Depends: xorg-input-abi-20
                             Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.14.99.902)`

So I then tried to install either `xserver-xorg-core` or `xorg-input-abi-20`, but then I get

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.`

I have also tried using `aptitude` to install the aforementioned packages, but that actually crashed my Ubuntu GUI system and so I had to reinstall Ubuntu after that and I don't think that approach works.